# Not able to install "Visual studio installer" in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, deployment, installation

I have installed Visual Studio 2015. I want to install "Visual Studio Installer" project. When I tried to install I found following error.

[image: Installation failed]

Can any one please help me?

I have tried `InstallerProjects.vsix` installer. I got following error:

```
27-Mar-19 9:45:06 PM - VSIXInstaller.NoApplicableSKUsException: This extension 
    is not installable on any currently installed products.
       at VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall(Boolean isRepairSupported)
       VSIXInstaller.App.InitializeInstall()
       System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved by installing visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you download [Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects) that only support the VS 2017/2019, please download [Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects) and install it.

[image]

Usually, we can also go to Tools-Extensions and Updates-Online, search the installer project and find it to download and install.